# SQL ORDER BY - pagination issue

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to workout a pagination:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT CVE_ORDEN_DET, ORDEN_TRABAJO_DET, NUM_MUESTRA, NUM_ESPECIMEN FROM colado_det WHERE CVE_OBRA = ? ORDER BY NUM_MUESTRA LIMIT ?,  30")) {
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $obdt, $page);    
$stmt->execute();  
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($id,$rf, $nm, $ne);     
while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {$arr_id[] = $id; $arr_rf[] = $rf;$arr_nm[] = $nm;$arr_ne[] = $ne; }
} else {echo ("Error conectando a la base de datos"); ;}
```

I think that the code is ok (This is just a part of the pagination), the problem is that when displaying the results, the program shows 30 rows, and the 30th row (From at least one page) appears in the next page (At start), wich results in a lose of one record.

When I use ORDER BY DESC, the problem doesn't seems to appear, however use descending order is not suitable for the needs of the users, so I need to find what is causing this, and how can I fix it.

I think that the problem lies in the sql, not the PHP, can somebody help me to confirm this, or give me a hint about what could be causing this? Please!

Some documentation is welcome. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

First part of pagination:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM colado_det where fecha = ?")) {
$stmt->bind_param('s', $asdfg);    
$stmt->execute();  
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($counting);  
$stmt->fetch();    
    $all = $counting;
    $page = round($page, 0);
    $page = (30)*($page); 
    $counting = $counting / 30;
    $counting = ceil($counting);
    if($counting<1){$counting=1;}
} else {echo ("Error conectando a la base de datos");}
```

The page variable recieves a number via $_GET; it's a number that later is multiplied by [Number of records to show], to get the record number to part from.

I tested it and it only lacks one record when using ORDER BY clause.

Comment: How are you setting your $page variable? Please add that code.

Comment: what is the value of $page when you are changing pages. If I want the first 30 rows, it should be 0 for example. If I want the second set of 30 rows, it should be 30.

Comment: it should be something like: `$startRow = (($page - 1) * 30);` .. Page 1 would evaluate to 0 and you'd get `LIMIT 0, 30` which would be 0 to 29, page 2 would evaluate to 30 and you'd get 30 through 59 etc... then change your bind_param to `$stmt->bind_param('ss', $obdt, $startRow);`

Comment: Thanks guys, I tried adding and substracting 1 to the $startRow; as Gary said, but i had no luck

Comment: Please see my answer, and try it without all the $page and $counting calculations in the EDIT, those are unecessary

Comment: I will do it, many thanks; i'm going back here, later; maybe tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM colado_det where fecha = ?")) {
$stmt->bind_param('s', $asdfg);    
$stmt->execute();  
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($counting);  
$stmt->fetch();    
    $all = $counting;
    $page = round($page, 0);
    $page = (30)*($page); 
    $counting = $counting / 30;
    $counting = ceil($counting);
    if($counting<1){$counting=1;}
} else {echo ("Error conectando a la base de datos");}
```

I'm really not sure what you're trying to accomplish here, this is convoluted.

should be something like this;

```
// assuming $page is already set with the current page and you already have a variable holding $totalCount
// but I will set them here for continuity;
$page = 1;
$totalCount = 538; // this is actually unnecessary for this, but is used to set up the display and make sure you don't run the query past the last page
$startRow = (($page - 1) * 30); // page should ONLY hold the current page they're on
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT CVE_ORDEN_DET, ORDEN_TRABAJO_DET, NUM_MUESTRA, NUM_ESPECIMEN FROM colado_det WHERE CVE_OBRA = ? ORDER BY NUM_MUESTRA LIMIT ?,  30")) {
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $obdt, $startRow);    
$stmt->execute();  
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($id,$rf, $nm, $ne);     
while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {$arr_id[] = $id; $arr_rf[] = $rf;$arr_nm[] = $nm;$arr_ne[] = $ne; }
} else {echo ("Error conectando a la base de datos"); ;}
```

Comment: Many Thanks Gary, It's requested via AJAX, the page variable holds only the current page, i'm reviewing my code; but I really think it's related to SQL more than PHP. Somebody save me please :(

Answer (score 0):

You are using string for `LIMIT`.

```
$stmt->bind_param('si', $obdt, $startRow);
```